# How do I prevent the padding property from changing width or height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, padding

I am creating a site with `DIV`s. Everything's working out except when I create a DIV. I create them like this (example):

```
newdiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

When I add the `padding-left` property, the width of the `DIV` changes to 220px, and I want it to remain at 200px.

Let's say I create another `DIV` named `anotherdiv` exactly the same as `newdiv`, and put it inside of `newdiv` but `newdiv` has no padding and `anotherdiv` has `padding-left: 20px`. I get the same thing, `newdiv`'s width will be 220px.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm sad to say, but I like how IE handles this... Makes much more sense to me ...

Answer (score 459):

Add property:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

**Note:** This **won't work** in Internet Explorer below version 8.

Comment: This is a great solution for borders, but how does this help for padding?

Comment: This is pure magic! - It fixes the box model we all know and hate! i.e. makes it work the way intuition suggests it should - rather than the specs - but as far as I know doesn't break any specs either :D This article clarifies it well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779434/preventing-padding-propety-from-changing-width-or-height-in-css

Comment: @technicalbloke Your link just goes back to this question.

Comment: Whoops yeah, copy and paste cock up. This is the link I meant to share... http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Many of you should consider the width: auto trick below.  Works across browsers, less code, etc.

Comment: this doesn't work for padding fully...meaning if i have 20px padding top+bottom combined and 0 px height. then height is still 20px. But if i make height 20 then height is still 20. That sucks..

Comment: @Muhammad: Put a 20px sized dragon into a box of size 40px and shrink the box. Guess what the minimum size is before the dragon gets angry. Your comment is invalid and will get eaten by the dragon.

Comment: thank you so much! Short explanation: "box-sizing" sets what the dimensions should include (e.g. should the specified width INCLUDE padding & margin?). Day is saved!

Comment: Just a note that the vendor-specific properties are no longer necessary in the latest Chrome and Safari. `box-sizing` is all you need.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but box-sizing doesn't seem to fix the width in Chrome 65 https://jsfiddle.net/q7h4zg2e/

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` works on Firefox, I don't need the `-moz-` prefix.

Answer (score 41):

Put a div in your newdiv with `width: auto` and `margin-left: 20px`

Remove the padding from newdiv.

[The W3 Box model page has good info.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: Why use two divs when you can use one?

Answer (score 37):

Try this

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 14):

If you would like to indent text within a div without changing the size of the div use the CSS `text-indent` instead of `padding-left`.

```css
.indent {
  text-indent: 1em;
}
.border {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  Non indented
</div>

<br>

<div class="border indent">
  Indented
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that I found worked for my fixed width div. box-sizing did not stop the padding from impacting the width unfortunately, so thanks a tonne for pointing out this awesome little property.

Answer (score 14):

A lot of the answers above are correct, but provided little explanation, so i decided to add this for anyone that might need it.

By default, every element `box-sizing` parameter is set to `content-box`.
Which means, that if you set an element width to 200px and then add a padding of 20px on both horizontal end, this would result to a total width of 240px for that element.

to fix this, you simply need to update the `box-sizing` parameter and set this to `border-box` in your css. Or you can do this for all elements by simply adding the following.

```
* {
     box-sizing: border-box 
  }
```

This tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height.

So for an element set to `border-box` with a width of 200px, and a padding of 20px on both sides, it's total width would still remain 200px (160px as content box and 40px as padding).

Hope that helps. [You read more on css box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 9):

simply add  `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: This is simply exactly the same as what other answers already say here.

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; = perfect answer - uncomplicated- short- works

Answer (score 0):

> when I add the padding-left property,
>   the width of the DIV changes to 220px

Yes, that is exactly according to the standards. That's how it's supposed to work.

> Let's say I create another DIV named
>   anotherdiv exactly the same as newdiv,
>   and put it inside of newdiv but newdiv
>   has no padding and anotherdiv has
>   padding-left: 20px. I get the same
>   thing, newdiv's width will be 220px;

No, newdiv will remain 200px wide.

Comment: Guffa, that's not how the standards are supposed to work at all. Padding is definitely not supposed to affect the dimensions of the element to which it's being applied. With the greatest respect, is it possible you're confusing 'padding' with 'margin'?

Comment: Yes, the padding is definitely supposed to affect the dimensions of the element. I think that it's you who is confused... how do you propose that the margin would affect the dimensions of the element?

Comment: Actually, you know I think we're both right in a way. I'm so used to coping with the effects that I'd entirely forgotten the standard. I found a good explanation here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: So, my apologies Mr Guffa. But for practical purposes (which is after all what we're talking about) my advice is still good no?

Comment: Well, you are right so far as that there is a box model bug, but it doesn't apply to this question... :)

Comment: Yes, what Guffa said is correct in that it's behaving according to the standard.  However, I don't think that's what the person who asked this question wanted to know.  Pramod's answer was much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in all cases, with this the extra padding included in predefined width

box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score -2):

just change your div width to 160px
if you have a padding of 20px it adds 40px extra to the width of your div so you need to subtract 40px from the width in order to keep your div looking normal and not distorted with extra width on it and your text all messed up.

Comment: This is the same as the answer given by @rvarcher.