# How to make padding in a div go inward

Tags: css, html, padding

So I'm trying to add padding to a div box but it just makes the box itself bigger and throws off the design, any ideas on how to stop it doing that, here's the CSS code

```
#mainbox {
background-color:#111111;
padding:0px;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;
border:solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: see possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779434/preventing-padding-propety-from-changing-width-or-height-in-css

Answer (score 3):

The CSS3 [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property is probably exactly what you want:

```
#mainbox {
    background-color:#111111;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:90px;
    border:solid 1px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By default, `width` only applies to the content, and `margin` and `padding` is added after the fact. So if your `width` is `90px`, and you add a padding of `10px`, your `div` will be `100px`.

The `box-sizing` property in CSS3 makes the browser include `border`, `margin`, and `padding` with `width`, making math a little easier, especially when you don't know the widths of everything beforehand.

**Note:** the `padding-box` property is not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Check the sample I have attached. I used it with hover. you can use directly too.

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin:50px;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```